# create new list and append to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to learn python. Assuming I have the below two dict().

- In the 1st dict, it includes user info and the reporting line structures.
- In the 2nd dict, it includes item counts belong to each individual.

I want to compare again these two dict and sum up the total item counts then display the result under name_S. The outcome is shown as follow:

```
data_set_1 = { 'id': 'mid',
                'name': 'name_S',
                'directory': [
                    {
                        'id': 'eid_A',
                        'name': 'name_A',
                        'directory': []
                    },
                    { 'id': 'eid_B',
                      'name': 'name_B',
                      'directory': []
                    },
                    { 'id': 'eid_C',
                      'name': 'name_C',
                      'directory': [
                                  {'id': 'eid_C1',
                                  'name': 'name_C1',
                                  'directory': []},
                                  {'id': 'eid_C2',
                                  'name': 'name_C2',
                                  'directory': []}]
                    }]}

data_set_2 = { 'eid_A': 5,
               'eid_F': 3,
               'eid_G': 0,
               'eid_C': 1,
               'eid_C1': 10,
               'eid_C2': 20 
              }
```

Result:

```
{'name_S': 36}
```

I'm able to get the result if I did this way:

```
def combine_compare(data_set_1, data_set_2):
    combine_result = dict()

    combine_id = data_set_1['id']
    combine_name = data_set_1['name']
    combine_directory = data_set_1['directory']

    if combine_directory:
        combine_item_sum = 0 
        combine_item_count = data_set_2.get(combine_id, 0)

        for combine_user in combine_directory:
            # Recursion starts
            for i in [combine_compare(combine_user, data_set_2)]:

                for key, value in i.items():
                    combine_item_sum += value

        combine_result[combine_name] = combine_item_sum + combine_item_count
    else:
        combine_result[combine_name] = data_set_2.get(combine_id, 0)

    return combine_result
```

Now if I want to include the ids that have item counts in the final result, something like this:

```
#if there is result and directory is not None under name_S
{'name_S': [36, ('eid_A', 'eid_C', eid_C1', 'eid_C2')]}

#if there is no result and directory is not None under name_S, display a default str
{'name_S': [0, ('Null')]}

#if there is result and directory is None under name_S, display name_S id
{'name_S': [1, ('mid')]}
```

My original idea is to create a list and append the counts and ids but I'm struggling how I can accomplish this. Here is what I try but the list is not returning the outcome I'm expecting and I'm not sure how I can append the count in the list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def combine_compare(data_set_1, data_set_2):
    combine_result = dict()

    # Creating a new list 
    combine_list = list()

    combine_id = data_set_1['id']
    combine_name = data_set_1['name']
    combine_directory = data_set_1['directory']

    if combine_directory:
        combine_item_sum = 0 
        combine_item_count = data_set_2.get(combine_id, 0)

        for combine_user in combine_directory:
            # Recursion starts
            for i in [combine_compare(combine_user, data_set_2)]:

                for key, value in i.items():
                    combine_item_sum += value

            # Trying to append the ids where count > 0
            if data_set_2.get(combine_user['id'], 0) != 0:
              combine_list.append(combine_user['id'])

        combine_result[combine_name] = combine_item_sum + combine_item_count
    else:
        combine_result[combine_name] = data_set_2.get(combine_id, 0)

    # Trying to print the list to see the results
    print(combine_list)

    return combine_result
```

Comment: Ugh, this code is bulk, which make it hard to read and may be reduced a lot. Also I don't understand why `name_S` is 36, while counting `data_set_2` values would be 39?

Comment: For counting you may reduce code by using `len(dict.keys())` or `sum(dict.values())` (for `name_S`) where you need it, for list key, e.g. `data_set_1["directory"]` number of dirs would be simply calling `len` on this key.

Comment: `data_set_2.get(combine_user['id'], 0) != 0` you have id as string and you make fallback as `int`, that's wrong, you should just use `data_set_2.get(combine_user['id'])` as the result will be `None` if key not exist and will result as `False` and skip `if`.

Comment: Actually you no need `combine_list` as it not used at all. You just append it and print, but not adding into result.

Comment: You have the following problems: your data is badly structured, as when you don't have result you still have empty dict `{}` without keys, `name_S` is a dict in a dict, should be simpler like variable `name_S = 5`, other issues produced because of this data structure, probably.

Comment: If you can manage data structure, I would suggest you something like this `{"dirs": []}` - this is empty result you will get if there are nothing, `{"dirs": [{"id": "mid", "name": "name_S", "dirs": []}]}` - when you have only root element and other will be nested as following.

Answer (score 0):

So what i understood from your question is that you want to know which ids mentioned in data_set_2 are there in data_set_1 and what is there sum. The following code is my version of solving the above mentioned problem.

```
data_set_1 = { 'id': 'mid',
                'name': 'name_S',
                'directory': [
                    {
                        'id': 'eid_A',
                        'name': 'name_A',
                        'directory': []
                    },
                    { 'id': 'eid_B',
                      'name': 'name_B',
                      'directory': []
                    },
                    { 'id': 'eid_C',
                      'name': 'name_C',
                      'directory': [
                                  {'id': 'eid_C1',
                                  'name': 'name_C1',
                                  'directory': []},
                                  {'id': 'eid_C2',
                                  'name': 'name_C2',
                                  'directory': []

                                  }
                                ]
                    }
                ]
            }

data_set_2 = { 'eid_A': 5,
               'eid_F': 3,
               'eid_G': 0,
               'eid_C': 1,
               'eid_C1': 10,
               'eid_C2': 20 
              }
value = 0
final_result={}
def compare(d1,d2):
    global value
    temp_result={}
    if d1['name'] not in temp_result:
        temp_result[d1['name']]=[]

    for items in d1['directory']:
        if items['directory']:
            temp_value=compare(items,d2)
            temp_result[d1['name']].append(temp_value)
        result=check_for_value(items,d2)
        if result:
            value+=result
            temp_result[d1['name']].append(items['id'])
    return temp_result

def check_for_value(d,d2):
    if d['id'] in d2:    
        return d2[d['id']]

final_result=compare(data_set_1,data_set_2)
final_result['value']=value
print("final_result:",final_result)
```

Which gives you an output dict which tells you exactly under which name does those ids come under.

The output is as follows:

```
final_result: {'value': 36, 'name_S': ['eid_A', {'name_C': ['eid_C1', 'eid_C2']}, 'eid_C']}
```

You can change the structure of the final result to make it exactly how you want it to be. Let me know if you have any trouble understanding the program.